# Не работает пагинация на page/2

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, почему при переходе на 2ю,3ю страницы пагинации выдаёт ошибку

```
"Oops! That page can’t be found."
```

1я страница показывается нормально.
Шаблон страниц с пагинацией, это шаблон категорий - taxonomy-product_cat.php
Использую такой код:

```
parse_str($query_string, $args);

if (isset($_POST['count_product'])) {
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['count_product'];
}else{
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 8;
}

query_posts( $args );

?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<!-- Start Pagination Area -->
<?php
paging_nav();

wp_reset_query();
```

Функция вывода пагинации:

```
//Пагинация
function paging_nav() {

    global $wp_query;

    // Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 )
        return;
    ?>
    <?php
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    $args = array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type' => 'list',
        'prev_text' => '|<',
        'next_text' => '>|',
        'add_args' => false
    );
    ?>
    <div class="pagination-area">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <div class="pagination">
                    <ul>
                        <?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

В настройках - Постоянные ссылки выбирал все варианты, но ошибка не устраняется.
Кстати на главной странице "Витрина" пагинация нормально работает, а на странице категорий не работает

Comment: Как у вас строится permalink? Были проблемы с пагинацией, если насильно добавляли в конце .html Попробуйте поставить стандартные настройки построения ссылки и попробуйте тот же функционал на другом шаблоне. Что-то должно натолкнуть на ответ

Comment: >Были проблемы с пагинацией, если насильно добавляли в конце .html

Comment: Как-то не понятно, это был вопрос или ответ? Насильно ничего не делалось.  
Кстати если в файл functions.php добавить этот код: `add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 4;' ), 20 );`
то пагинация начинает нормально работать на всех страницах.
С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: >Попробуйте поставить стандартные настройки построения ссылки и попробуйте тот же функционал на другом шаблоне

Comment: Это что значит? Вы имеете ввиду, что так просто нельзя понять, откуда ошибка? Поставил стандартные настройки, на главной странице "Витрине" пагинация нормально работает, а именно на странице категорий выдаёт вышеприведённую ошибку. И кстати на странице категорий значение $wp_query->max_num_pages почему-то выводит 1, хоть и задавал для $wp_query->posts_per_page разные значения

Comment: Ну что непонятного то? Пагинация как строится? Если нестандартно, то поставьте стандартно. Насчет html - случай из практики, говорю, что это ломало пагинацию на сайте. Смените шаблон на другой, оставив те же настройки WP и набор плагинов. Проделав все методом исключения наткнетесь на решение, или хотя бы будет понятно куда копать

Comment: >Насчет html - случай из практики, говорю, что это ломало пагинацию на сайте

Comment: я ведь говорил, что насильно ничего не делалось, в конце ничего не добавлялось. Такую практику я не делал.

Comment: >Смените шаблон на другой, оставив те же настройки WP и набор плагинов

Comment: из плагинов только один - woocommerce, других плагинов нет, и код пагинации вы видели. При чём здесь не стандартно? Скажите тогда, что в этом коде не стандартно?

Comment: решил проблему установкой такого кода: `add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 4;' ), 20 );`